# Loss for Multi-label Classification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, classification

I am working on a multi-label classification problem. My gt labels are of shape `14 x 10 x 128`, where `14` is the `batch_size`, `10` is the `sequence_length`, and `128` is the vector with values `1` if the item in sequence belongs to the object and `0` otherwise.

My output is also of same shape: `14 x 10 x 128`. Since, my input sequence was of varying length I had to pad it to make it of fixed length `10`. I'm trying to find the loss of the model as follows:

```py
total_loss = 0.0
unpadded_seq_lengths = [3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 3, 2, 8, 5, 3, 5, 7, 7, ...] # true lengths of sequences

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()

for data in training_dataloader:
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # shape of input 14 x 10 x 128
    output = model(data)
   
    batch_loss = 0.0
    for batch_idx, sequence in enumerate(output):
        # sequence shape is 10 x 128
        true_seq_len = unpadded_seq_lengths[batch_idx]
        
        # only keep unpadded gt and predicted labels since we don't want loss to be influenced by padded values
        predicted_labels = sequence[:true_seq_len, :] # for example, 3 x 128
        gt_labels =  gt_labels_padded[batch_idx, :true_seq_len, :] # same shape as above, gt_labels_padded has shape 14 x 10 x 128
        
        # loop through unpadded predicted and gt labels and calculate loss  
        for item_idx, predicted_labels_seq_item in enumerate(predicted_labels):
            
            # predicted_labels_seq_item and gt_labels_seq_item are 1D vectors of length 128
            gt_labels_seq_item = gt_labels[item_idx]
            current_loss = criterion(predicted_labels_seq_item, gt_labels_seq_item)                     
            total_loss += current_loss
            batch_loss += current_loss


    batch_loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Can anybody please check to see if I'm calculating loss correctly. Thanks

Update:

Is this the correct approach for calculating accuracy metrics?

```py
# batch size: 14
# seq length: 10

for epoch in range(10):
    TP = FP = TN = FN = 0.
    for x, y, mask in tr_dl:
        # mask shape: (10,)
        out = model(x) # out shape: (14, 10, 128)
        y_pred = (torch.sigmoid(out) >= 0.5).float().type(torch.int64) # consider all predictions above 0.5 as 1, rest 0
        y_pred = y_pred[mask] # y_pred shape: (14, 10, 10, 128)
        y_labels = y[mask] # y_labels shape: (14, 10, 10, 128)

        # do I flatten y_pred and y_labels?
        y_pred = y_pred.flatten()
        y_labels = y_labels.flatten()
        
        for idx, prediction in enumerate(y_pred):
            if prediction == 1 and y_labels[idx] == 1:
                # calculate IOU (overlap of prediction and gt bounding box)
                iou = 0.78 # assume we get this iou value for objects at idx
                if iou >= 0.5:
                    TP += 1
                else:
                    FP += 1
            elif prediction == 1 and y_labels[idx] == 0:
                FP += 1
            elif prediction == 0 and y_labels[idx] == 1:
                FN += 1
            else:
                TN += 1
          
     EPOCH_ACC = (TP + TN) / (TP + TN + FP + FN)
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the encoding of your data. What does the last dimension of your input data (with size `128`) represent exactly? I get how the gt is encoded but how is the input encoded?

Comment: So the last dimension of input represents word embedding from a pretrained language model (GloVE)

Comment: And just to confirm, you have a total of `128` possible labels for a single sequence element, correct?

Comment: That's correct. And each element in the sequence will be assigned one or more labels.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually recommended to stick with batch-wise operations and avoid going into single-element processing steps while in the main training loop. One way to handle this case is to make your dataset return padded inputs and labels with additionally a mask that will come useful for loss computation. In other words, to compute the loss term with sequences of varying sizes, we will use a mask instead of doing individual slices.

##### Dataset

The way to proceed is to make sure you build the mask in the dataset and not in the inference loop. Here I am showing a minimal implementation that you should be able to transfer to your dataset without much hassle:

```
class Dataset(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def __len__(self):
        return 100

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        i = random.randint(5, SEQ_LEN) # for demo puporse, generate x with random length
        x = torch.rand(i, EMB_SIZE)
        y = torch.randint(0, N_CLASSES, (i, EMB_SIZE))

        # pad data to fit in batch
        pad = torch.zeros(SEQ_LEN-len(x), EMB_SIZE)
        x_padded = torch.cat((pad, x))
        y_padded = torch.cat((pad, y))

        # construct tensor to mask loss
        mask = torch.cat((torch.zeros(SEQ_LEN-len(x)), torch.ones(len(x))))

        return x_padded, y_padded, mask
```

Essentially in the `__getitem__`, we not only pad the input `x` and target `y` with zero values, we also construct a simple mask containing the positions of the padded values in the currently processed element.

Notice how:

- `x_padded`, shaped `(SEQ_LEN, EMB_SIZE)`
- `y_padded`, shaped `(SEQ_LEN, N_CLASSES)`
- `mask`, shaped `(SEQ_LEN,)`

are all three tensors which are shape invariant across the dataset, yet `mask` contains the padding information necessary for us to compute the loss function appropriately.

##### Inference

The loss you've used [`nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html), is the correct one since it's a multi-dimensional loss used for binary classification. In other words, you can use it here in this *multi-label* classification task, considering each one of the 128 logits as an individual binary prediction. Do not use [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html)) as suggested elsewhere, since the **softmax** will push a single logit (*i.e.* class), which is the behaviour required for *single-label* classification tasks.

Therefore, in the training loop, we simply have to apply the mask to our loss.

```
for x, y, mask in dl:
   y_pred = model(x)
   loss = mask*bce(y_pred, y)
   # backpropagation, loss postprocessing, logs, etc.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response. Can I use a similar way to calculate accuracy as well (using mask)?

Comment: So right now, I'm calculating tp, fp, tn, and tn per epoch and then using these to calculate accuracy and f1. I'm doing this in loop, similar to my loss calculation approach. Can you provide a similar example on how I can compute these values without iterating each loop? I can add my accuracy calculation code if it's not clear.

Comment: Also, for the final loss, do I just do `loss.backward()` followed by `total_loss += torch.sum(loss)`?

Comment: (1) Yes, you can still use the mask tensors for the accuracy, but you should mask the tensors instead of doing a multiplication: for example, doing `y_pred[mask]` and `y[mask]` before computing the actual accuracy terms. (2) Not sure what you mean by "w/o iterating each loop"? If you want to compute the metrics on your training set online, you have to do so batch-wise. (3) Indeed, with my approach doing `loss.backward()` will compute the gradients for this batch, loss is already a scalar-tensor so `total_loss += loss.item()` would suffice (but you'll have to normalize it with nb of batches.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain a little bit why the multiplication with mask wouldn't work in case of accuracy metrics? And isn't `y` and `y_pred` already padded in your example above?

So basically when it comes to computing accuracy metrics, we only want to get the non-zero predictions and gt and that is what `y_pred[mask]` and `y[mask]` would do. Did I get that right?

Comment: You never know because `y_pred`  and `y` might actually contain zero values among their "non-padded" values. However, the reason for this masking is different, it has to do with how you compute your accuracy, if you compute some kind of average at some point across your sequence, you will face a error because averaging over padded sequences (even when masked) won't be the same as averaging ***exclusively*** on  the valid values. Do you see the difference? Just look at `y*mask` and `y[mask]` (they don't have the same number of elements which will output different counts).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'll try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I think `loss = mask*bce(y_pred, y)` won't be scalar so we might have to do something like `final_loss = loss.sum()/mask.sum()`. Does that make sense?

Comment: You should rather have it averaged and backpropagated straight away as: `loss = loss.mean(); loss.backward()`

Comment: If I have class weights and I want to use weighted loss to handle class imbalance, do I need to use `reduction=none` with `bce` and then do this: `loss = (loss * weights).mean()` ?

Comment: Since you are using [`nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html) you should provide that `weights` tensor to `pos_weight` argument when initializing the loss module rather than doing the multiplication manually ;).

Comment: I've added accuracy calculation loop in my original post. Could you please verify if I'm doing it properly? Thank you.

Comment: I believe your mask is shaped `(batch_size, seq_len)`, and not `(seq_len,)`. You should first expand your mask to the shape of `y` and `y_pred` with something like `mask = mask[:,:,None, None].expand_as(y)`, then mask by flattening the tensors: `y.flatten()[mask.flatten()]`. This will return a flattened tensor containing only the *valid* values from `y`. Why don't you calculate the accuracy on the whole masked tensor instead of iterating over it? Otherwise, I recommend using an existing implementation for the accuracy, it's a widespread function, or at least comparing your results with it.

Comment: The loss that you suggested works but of the `128` objects, most of them are `true negatives`. This results in very low precision, recall, and F1 score (close to `0`). How do I update the loss so that it takes into account the huge number of `true negatives`? The loss seems to be going down but the F1 isn't changing a lot. Thanks.

Comment: For accuracy, I believe I have to iterate over the predictions because I want to calculate `IOU` for the true positives. Is that the correct approach? Should the `tp`, `tn`, `fp`, and `fn` be accumulated for all the batches and used to calculate accuracy after every epoch?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need for the first part of the question, there are already loss functions implemented in tensorflow: https://medium.com/@aadityaura_26777/the-loss-function-for-multi-label-and-multi-class-f68f95cae525. Yours is just `tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits`, but you need to set the weight.

The second part of the question is not straightforward, because there's conditioning on the IOU, generally, when you do machine learning, you should heavily depend on matrix multiplication, in your case, you probably need to pre-calculate the IOU -> 1 or 0 as a vector, then multiply with the `y_pred` , element-wise, this will give you the modified `y_pred` . After that, you can use any accuracy available function to calculate the final result.

Comment: Not sure how this answers OP's question for Pytorch users. Multi-label classification tasks should be handled with a binary entropy loss on logits. PyTorch provides such a function with an optional weight argument to set the weight of positive instances. Could you clarify your second paragraph?

Comment: The second part is to rely on using matrix multiplication instead of for loop. Similar to the masked approach another person answered. I

In this case, you want to pre-calculate all the IOU, which is similar to the mask mentioned above. aka, create a tensor of IOU_mask = IOU, and  replace values >= 0.75 to 1, and value <0.75 to 0, so the IOU_mask will be from [ 0.25, 0.9 0.1, 0.8,...] to [ 0, 1, 0, 1,...]. When you element-wise multiplication, `prediction = prediction*IOU_mask`, this will replace the if-else. 

Then you can use any accuracy function, see here: https://bre.is/QcDKrcwE

Answer (score 0):

if you can use the [CROSSENTROPYLOSS](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) instead of `BCEWithLogitsLoss` there is something called `ignore_index`. you can use it to exclude your padded sequences. the difference between the 2 losses is the activation function used (`softmax` vs `sigmoid`). but I think you can still use the `CROSSENTROPYLOSS`for binary classification as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does `CrossEntropyLoss` work for multi-label classification problem?

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I misunderstood your problem statement. you can't use `cross-entropy` loss as you are not predicting a single number, you want the entire 128 values in your vector to be compared individually. in that case, just replacing the loss won't work.